# Using ng-click in directive's template to call other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use `ng-click` inside my directive's template, but I don't know how can I pass another directive to it. My code is as follows:

```
template: `
    <ul><li ng-repeat="link in $ctrl.map" ng-click="page-scroll-to={{link[1]}}">{{link[0]}}</li></ul>
`
```

Secound directive:

```
app.directive('pageScrollTo', () => {
    return {
        link(scope, el, attrs) {
            const scroll = attrs.pageScrollTo;

            window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
        }
    };
});
```

It, obviously, doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Comment: Where is your second directory?

Comment: You mean directive? I've posted it.

Comment: You shall create scroll service and call it on click. You have directive name written inside `ng-click` that does not make sense.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. ng-click expects an angular expression, not the name of a directive.

Comment: So I can't call directive on `ng-click`? Okay, I understand.

Comment: why there is need of click event ?What you expect there for scroll dir?

Comment: It's like clicking on an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive, just put a click handler on the element.

template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="link in $ctrl.map" page-scroll-to="link[1]">
        {{link[0]}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

the directive:

```
app.directive('pageScrollTo', () => {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on("click", function clickHandler(e) {
                 var scroll = scope.$eval(attrs.pageScrollTo);
                 window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
            });
        }
    };
});
```